# A synonymous word for "wrong desire"

Tags: meaning

A man said to a girl "don't grow a wrong-desire about me in your mind". Thus, please let me know a single word for "wrong-desire"?

Comment: Wrongness of desire is in the eyes of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

Temptation? I hope that has a negative enough connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps other synonyms might be "lust" or "flesh-cravings" . . . or "craze" or "appetite".

Answer (score 1):

"A  ***forbidden, impure or unrequited*** desire" are three nuances that can be used in that sentence.

***forbidden*** would imply going against society's acceptable norms

***impure*** implies unchaste

***unrequited*** would mean that the feelings could not be reciprocated

Answer (score 1):

*don't grow a wrong-desire about me in your mind* doesn't sound like a proper english idiom or phrase to my ear; it sounds like a poor translation.

If I were to try and make it into something that "sounds english", I would say: **Don't fantasize about me.**

Answer (score 0):

Although we would normally think of this if the desire went the other direction, the OED’s definitions of ***perverse*** suggest this may be exactly the word you’re looking for here:

> - Turned away from the right way or from what is right or good; perverted; wicked.
> - Not in accordance with the accepted standard or practice; incorrect; wrong.

Which source also gives for ***perverted*** the following sense:

> - Turned from the right way, from the proper use, from truth to error, etc.; wicked; distorted; misapplied.

So this would appear to be *perverse desire*, because it is wrong, or incorrect, or discordant with accepted social norms.

Answer (score 0):

The variety of answers given above is indicative of the fact that it depends on which type of desire the poor girl is tempted to develop. The way I read it is that the guy tells her not to develop romantic feelings for her when you might say:

> Don't develop a crush on me.

In fact especially amongst younger people *crush* is becoming a verb.

> Don't crush on me.

However, if he is telling her that he likes their relationship they way it is and he doesn't want her to expect a diamond ring, then the he might say:

> Don't fall for me.

(Which is common, idiomatic shorthand for *don't fall in love with me*.)